# How do I find the shortest text like an autocomplete?

Tags: string, algorithm

I've got a list of strings and I want to find the shortest unique way to identify them. It is a bit like an autocomplete but, for a given set, will always be the shortest identifiable way.

As an example.

```
PA  for Paddington
PE  for Penryn
PLO for Plymouth
PLP for Plympton
PO  for Portsmouth
Q   for Quebec
```

I've got several thousand names (they aren't cities, but programmes names).

I need a relatively short sequence that will be in order (for the above list, both the key and value are in order).

Any techniques/algorithms for this would be useful.

I know I'll have to code it (using PHP), but as long as I can understand the algorithm, I'm happy.

I think I have to build a tree of values as they currently stand, then start navigating that tree one character at a time, ignoring sequences that have a single option (the L and Y in Plymouth/Plympton for example).

So, starting with the Q in Quebec, I'd find that all the way through the tree, all subsequent letters are only used once, so Q is enough at that stage.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

Answer (score 0):

You can begin by creating a hashtable structure that maps the possible substrings to a list of all the names beginning with that substring. This could end up being a pretty big data structure, but since you can short-circuit the moment you reach a unique substring, you can keep the size from getting unreasonably large. Here's an example using C#:

```
var names = new[]{
"Paddington",
"Penryn",
"Plymouth",
"Plympton",
"Portsmouth",
"Quebec"};
// First, for any given subsequence, find groups of names that
// start with it.
var groups = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
ILookup<string, string> newGroups;
List<string> namesToProcess = names.ToList();
int i = 0;
do
{
    // Stop looking at names once we're getting substrings too long for them.
    namesToProcess = namesToProcess.Where(n => n.Length >= i).ToList();
    newGroups = namesToProcess.ToLookup(n => n.Substring(0, i));
    foreach(var g in newGroups)
    {
        groups.Add(g.Key, g.ToList());
    }
    // stop looking at names once we find that they're the only ones
    // matching a given substring.
    namesToProcess = namesToProcess
        .Except(newGroups
            .Where(g => g.Count() == 1)
            .Select(g => g.Single()))
        .ToList();
    i++;
} while (newGroups.Any());
```

Now that it's easy to look up how many items match a given sub-sequence, it's a simple task to build the best code for any given name. You start with an empty string, and add each letter which helps you narrow down the number of possibilities:

```
// Now build the best code to use for each name
var codeNamePairs = names.ToDictionary(n => 
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int j = 0; j < n.Length; j++)
    {
        var prefix = n.Substring(0, j+1);
        var withSamePrefix = groups[prefix];
        // Only add the next letter if it helps to narrow down
        // the possibilities
        if(withSamePrefix.Count != groups[sb.ToString()].Count)
        {
            sb.Append(n[j]);
        }
        if(withSamePrefix.Count == 1)
        {
            // Once we reach a prefix that's unique to this name,
            // then we know we've built the code we want.
            break;
        }
    }
    return sb.ToString();
});
```

I'm not sure how easily the code will translate to PHP, but hopefully I conveyed the general idea well enough.

Comment: I'd really love to hear why this answer got a -1 vote.

Comment: Thank you for this process. I built a tree of the letters from the names. I then walked the tree, picking out the non unique letters to build the shortened text. Worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score -1):

I would first sort the strings alphabetically. Then you have a list just like yours:

```
Paddington
Penryn
Plymouth
Plympton
Portsmouth
Quebec
```

Now, for each element starting from the top, I find the shortest string that both the previous and next element does not start with. In our case, it goes like this:

`Paddigton` can't have `P`, because the next element starts with it, but it can have `Pa`, because the next one does not start with it.

For `Penryn` we start with the previous id reduced by enough letters that `Penryn` starts with it - we take `a` away and keep the `P`. Now we repeat: the previous element starts with `P`, so we add one letter and get `Pe`. In this case both previous and next don't start with it, so we assign this id to `Penryn`

With `Plymouth`, repeating the steps above, we get the `Plymo` id.

When analyzing `Plympton`, the initial previous id reduction step will give us `Plym`, and we need to add just one letter to it so that both the previous and the next one don't start with this id.

And so on.

Now, this does not generate the same ids as you propose, however in my opinion, PLO does not serve as a good id for Plymouth from algorithmic point of view.